# Dynamic Titles in my codeigniter header.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a header.php I'm loading in my controllers for every page.  However I want to have dynamic titles for each page.  My idea was to pass a $title variable into the view as I'm loading it:

```
//Home Controller
function index()
{

    $data['title'] = "Dynamic Title";

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/home');
    $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

and then check for the $title variable in my header.php

```
<title>
    <?php if ($title)
        { 
            echo $title; 
        }
    else
        { 
            echo 'Default Title'; 
        }
    endif; ?>       
</title>
```

However this doesn't work and I get a blank page.  I think it is my syntax for the header.php but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would try doing a var dump of $title in the view, just to see if it's getting passed at all.

Also, you don't need "endif;" since you're ending the if statement with the last curly brace.

Comment: The endif was the problem... Rookie mistake :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

#### Proper `if` Syntax

Your syntax on the `if-statement` is a bit off. You can use either:

```
if (condition) {
  // do a
} else {
  // do b
}
```

Or

```
if (condition) :
  // do a
else : 
  // do b
endif;
```

You seem to have transposed the ending of the latter onto the former.

#### Using the Ternary Operator in Title

Once you've made that change, your title can be printed as easily as:

```
<title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : 'Default Title' ; ?></title>
```

#### Alternative View Loading

Another method of loading views is to work with a single template file:

```
$data['title'] = 'Foo Bar';
$data['content'] = 'indexPage';

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

This loads the `template.php` file as your view. Within this file you load your subsequent parts:

```
<?php $this->load->view("_header"); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view("_footer"); ?>
```

By no means is this necessary, but it may help you maintain brevity in your controller.